# How to correctly set gdpr_consent with ConsentSDK?

Tags: android, admob, mopub, gdprconsentform

I have a warning from AdMob about TCF. After dealing with their support for a few weeks and sending them proxy logs, they say that I'm setting the `npa` parameter correctly but that I'm not setting a `gdpr_consent` parameter. But I don't see any way to set that up and they haven't given me any extra info as to how I would set it.

I am using MoPub for mediation and aside from ConsentSDK I'm also setting the `npa` value on MoPub.

This is my MoPub code:

```
Map<String,String> npa = new HashMap<>();
        npa.put("npa",disablePersonalizedAds ? "1" : "0");
        builder.withMediatedNetworkConfiguration(GooglePlayServicesAdapterConfiguration.class.getName(), npa);
```

And this is my ConsentSDK code:

```
ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).setConsentStatus(disablePersonalizedAds ? ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED : ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED);
```

Does anyone know how to set that `gdpr_consent` value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

First, which version of the AdMob adapters are you using in your app? As of [v18.3.0.3](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-mediation/blob/master/AdMob/CHANGELOG.md) (Android) and [v7.53.1.2](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-mediation/blob/master/AdMob/CHANGELOG.md) (iOS) of the AdMob adapters, MoPub collects GDPR consent on behalf of Google. What that means is, you do not need to manually pass in the `npa` in that manner. You can remove that line of code if you are on newer adapter versions.

Second, MoPub currently doesn't support TCF per https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/best-practices/gdpr-guide/. As such, when using MoPub for mediation and Google as a demand source, there are no changes for publishers aside from the existing GDPR requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the info, didn't know about that. I'm on `18.2.0.3` so it looks like I'll have to update. Do I still need to use ConsentSDK?

Comment: @casolorz, if you update to newer adapter versions, MoPub will collect and pass the GDPR consent to Google in the adapters. You do not need to take additional actions in your app. Since you no longer need to present Google's consent dialog, you don't need to use their Consent SDK.

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark you as correct at least until I release an update and see if the error goes away.